# Unity3d lost directional light shadows after generate assetBundle (.unity3d file)

Tags: unity-game-engine, shadow

I am a unity developer. I build a project for load assetbundle. I was generate assetbundle (.unity3d) file and then load it to unity project. but all my shadows on assetbundle were lost. What is my problem? please kindly help me.

Comment: There are not any help me now

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and managed to solve it, it seems like instantiating through assetbundles did something to it's shader, I used this code to re-set all of the shaders in the scene and it worked for me.

```
Shader standardShader;

void Start() {
    standardShader = Shader.Find("Standard");
}

void changeShader() // because shadow for assetbundle is cucked.
{
    var renderers = FindObjectsOfType<Renderer>() as Renderer[];
    for (int i = 0; i < renderers.Length; i++)
        renderers[i].material.shader = standardShader;
}
```

and called it after all of the instantiating is done.

Hope this helps.

this is my post [Shadows for Instantiated Game Object bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44104202/shadows-for-instantiated-game-object-bug/44147787#44147787)