# Shadows for Instantiated Game Object bug?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a project and my next goal is to be able to instantiate a prefab during runtime, i managed to reach that far but I noticed that my instantiated prefabs doesn't have any shadows. I tried dragging the exact same object to the scene and it **can cast** shadow. I've did some googling and found many comments of this being a Unity3d bug in version 5, just curious whether anyone encountered the same problem and managed to find a roundabout way to fix this.

The prefabs I'm spawning are mostly all different.

The plane and cube with the shadow is dragged inside the scene whilst without shadow are instantiated.

[image]

Thanks alot for taking the time to read!

**EDIT 1**
So I've tried a couple of testing and trials and errors, and I noticed that the only difference between the game objects that have and doesn't have the shadow is that the gameobjects without the shadow was from an assetbundle loaded.

My problem seems to be similar to this guy's post

[Unity3d lost directional light shadows after generate assetBundle (.unity3d file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42291328/unity3d-lost-directional-light-shadows-after-generate-assetbundle-unity3d-file)

**EDIT 2**

I'm using the Unity version 5.5.1f1 if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like instantiating through assetbundles did something to it's shader, I used this code to re-set all of the shaders in the scene and it worked for me.

```
Shader standardShader;

void Start() {
    standardShader = Shader.Find("Standard");
}

void changeShader() // because shadow for assetbundle is cucked.
{
    var renderers = FindObjectsOfType<Renderer>() as Renderer[];
    for (int i = 0; i < renderers.Length; i++)
        renderers[i].material.shader = standardShader;
}
```

and called it after all of the instantiating is done.

Comment: Thanks, And maybe this `renderers [i].material.shader = Shader.Find (renderers [i].material.shader.name);` so as to preserve the original shader if it was something other than "standard"

Comment: Thanks to both @haru-the-potato and @Logic1 - I modified a method to include both answers and allows me to pass in a GameObject to target and worked great on my loaded AssetBundle objects:

`
void FixShaders(GameObject g)
{
    Renderer[] renderers = g.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < renderers.Length; i++)
        renderers[i].material.shader = 
            Shader.Find(renderers[i].material.shader.name);
 }`

Answer (score 1):

Go to your prefab and check the `mesh renderer`, it must have the `receive shadows` and `cast shadows` property activated like in the image:
[image]

Then remember to update your prefab:[image]

Drag one `prefab` to the scene, activate the `receive shadows` and `cast shadows` properties from the `mesh renderer` and finally `apply` changes.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help, I checked for the settings that you mentioned and unfortunately >< they were all set correctly, I've updated the post with some recent findings about my problem, hope it helps!